# Making Python script accessible system wide

Tags: python, linux, windows, shell, osx-leopard

Can someone tell me how to make my script callable in any directory?

My script simply returns the number of files in a directory. I would like it to work in any directory by invoking it, instead of first being copied there and then typing `python myscript.py`

I am using Mac OS X, but is there a common way to get it installed on Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your script starts with a suitable shebang line, such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And your script has the executable bit set (for Linux, OS X, and other Unix-like systems):

```
chmod +x myscript.py
```

And the path to your script is in your PATH environment variable:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:`pwd` # on Unix-like systems

SET PATH=%PATH%;\path\to # on Windows
```

Then you can call `myscript.py` from wherever you are.

Comment: using export PATH=${PATH}:`pwd`, will allow all scripts in the working directory to be accessed if they have chmod +x. How do I specify just one single file?

Comment: Yes it will. You can either put it in its own directory or in one where you keep other such scripts, e.g. `${HOME}/bin`.

Comment: Put it someplace like /usr/local/bin. You can even put a symlink there if you really want to keep your actual script someplace else

Comment: @Falmarri's suggestion means that other users should be able to run your script, if that is your intention.

Answer (score 0):

All of those operating systems should support a PATH environment variable which specifies directories that have executables that should be available everywhere. Make your script executable by `chmod +x` and place it into one of those directories (or add a new one to your PATH - I have `~/bin` for instance).

I don't know how to make new kinds of files directly executable on Windows, though, but I guess you could use a `.bat` file as a proxy.