# How to call python script like other brew,pip

Tags: python, shell

I made python script with arguments like this .

#### resize.py

```
def resize(path):
    # try resize action.

if  len(sys.argv) == 2:
    resize(sys.argv[1])
else:
    raise "you can't file path as argument."
```

And Now  I can use this script by 

`python /path/to/dir/resize.py my_picture.png`

But  I want to call this script anywhere from command line like  this

`./resize my_picture.png`

Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NikitaLeonov My os is mac os .

Comment: @NikitaLeonov: The same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/3743812/78845 ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the python shebang statement in order to call it without prefacing it with `python`, like so at the top of the `resize.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

You also need to make sure that you `chmod +x resize.py` your file in order to make it executable. That should get you going on Unix Systems.

Comment: Assuming it is a Unix system, you should probably also mention `chmod`ing it

Answer (score 1):

You can put the directory of the `resize` function in your path, or move your `resize` function to somewhere already in your path.

If you want to add it to your path, and it is located at `/foo/bar/resize`, then you would have to add `/foo/bar` to your path. You can do this by putting it in your `.bashrc` or something, like:

```
PATH=/foo/bar:$PATH
```

If you don't want to do that, you can just copy it into somewhere where binaries are already stored, like `/usr/bin`.

Also, don't forget to mark it executable, with `chmod +x resize`